# How to deal with labels in input pipeline?

Tags: tensorflow

I do have an images' names and labels as a list and I want to get a batch of 64 images/labels. I could get the images in a right way but for labels, its dimension is (64,8126). Each column has the same element 64 times. And rows consists 8126 original label values without getting shuffled.

I understand the problem that for every image tf.train.shuffle_batch considers the 8126 element label vector. But how would I pass only single element for each image?

```
def _get_images(shuffle=True):

"""Gets the images and labels as a batch"""

    #get image and label list
    _img_names,_img_class = _get_list() #list of image names and labels

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(_img_names)

    #reader
    image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

    #decode jpeg
    image_original = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
    label_original = tf.convert_to_tensor(_img_class,dtype=tf.int32)
    #print label_original

    #image preprocessing
    image = tf.image.resize_images(image_original, [224,224])
    float_image = tf.cast(image,dtype=tf.float32)
    float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
    #set the shape
    float_image.set_shape((224, 224, 3))
    #label_original.set_shape([8126]) #<<<<<=========== causes (64,8126) dimension label without shuffle

    #parameters for shuffle
    batch_size = 64
    num_preprocess_threads = 16
    num_examples_per_epoch = 8000
    min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
    min_queue_examples = int(num_examples_per_epoch *
                       min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

    if shuffle:
        images_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [float_image,label_original],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
    else:
        images_batch, label_original = tf.train.batch(
            [float_image,_img_class],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size)

    return images_batch,label_batch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use `tf.train.slice_input_producer`

```
# here _img_class should be a list
labels_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([_img_class])
...
images_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [float_image,labels_queue],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
        capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size,
        min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
```

Comment: Greatttt!! Thanks.. Much appreciated!